# Pandas search through dataframe for words missing diacritical marks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge some CSVs based on strings of province/district data from Brazil. However, in one CSV (df1) all of the provinces/distrcits are properly formatted, including the exact diacritical marks that the word should have. The other CSV (df2) has all the correct letters, but is missing the diacritical marks. Is there a way to loop through df1 (correct provinces/districts), pulling out all the unique names and then matching those to df2 (missing the diacritical marks)? Possibly something with .str.contains()?

Here is an example:

df1 has São Paulo

df2 has Sao Paulo

I would like the program to find that these two are the same and then replace Sao Paulo with São Paulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will be helpful for you !

```
import unicodedata

s = 'Campos do Jordão é um município que recebe bastante turistas ao longo do ano. A maior parte das pessoas costuma ir até lá nos meses em que faz frio, pois há mais atrações nessas épocas.'
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8'))
```

output : `Campos do Jordao e um municipio que recebe bastante turistas ao longo do ano. A maior parte das pessoas costuma ir ate la nos meses em que faz frio, pois ha mais atracoes nessas epocas.`

For your case, you can check the similarity with the result of the normalisation.